# Find number in the next line that matches the regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find this form of number `\s\d\d\s` in the simple `" 30 "` in the line and store it in int variable but I am not getting a match. How can I fix it?

**Simple:**

```
buildig 05:11 05:41 06:14 06:44 07:14 07:44 08:14 30 17:14 17:44 18:14 18:44 19:14 19:44
```

**Code:**

```
        Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(file)) {
    int lineNum = 0;
    while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scannerLines.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(" alle ")) {
            String nextLine = scannerLines.nextLine();
            Pattern pattern = 
                    Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\s");

            Matcher matcher = 
                    pattern.matcher(nextLine);                   
             System.out.println(matcher);

        }

    }
```

Comment: When you have **matcher** object, find all the occurences by looping over **matcher.find()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should compile your patter outside the loop. Then use the `Matcher.find()` for getting the next group that match your regexp, and later trim the value of the group (because of the whitespace in " 30 ").

```
Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\s");
int lineNum = 0;

Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
    lineNum++;
    while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scannerLines.nextLine();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        while (matcher.find()){
            int value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group().trim());
            System.out.println("Found " + value + " at line " + lineNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `matcher.find()`:

```
    Scanner scannerLines = new Scanner(file)) {
    int lineNum = 0;
    while (scannerLines.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scannerLines.nextLine();
        if (line.contains(" alle ")) {
            String nextLine = scannerLines.nextLine();
            Pattern pattern = 
                    Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\s");

            Matcher matcher = 
                    pattern.matcher(nextLine);  

           while(matcher.find()){                        
             System.out.println(matcher.group());
           }

        }

    }
```